# How to lower threshold for tfhub object detection model?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I'm using model tensorflow pretrained model from model zoo https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md **faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_oidv4**

It works fine, but I would like to lower threshold of the model to make it generate more bbox proposals. How can I do that? Recreate graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-export it using the [`export_inference_graphy.py` script](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/export_inference_graph.py).

E.g. like this (example copied from the `export_inference_graphy.py` script) to decrease the score threshold from 0.3 to 0.1.

```
python export_inference_graph \
--input_type image_tensor \
--pipeline_config_path path/to/model/pipeline.config \
--trained_checkpoint_prefix path/to/model/model.ckpt \
--output_directory path/to/exported_model_directory \
--config_override " \
        model{ \
          faster_rcnn { \
            second_stage_post_processing { \
              batch_non_max_suppression { \
                score_threshold: 0.1 \
              } \
            } \
          } \
        }"
```